# How to split a sentence for every "," symbol?

Tags: java, android, arrays, split

I know the normal one to split the sentence by using split function, but the problem is you need to declare how many variables you need, 
Example: Fighting,Action,Adventure,Racing,RPG

```
String[] GameGenreCodeSeparated = GameGenreCodeRAW.split(",");
listGameGenre.add(GameGenreCodeSeparated[0]);
listGameGenre.add(GameGenreCodeSeparated[1]);
listGameGenre.add(GameGenreCodeSeparated[2]);
```

How to add a list every ',' symbol, so a list can has 5 objects from that sentence dynamically, any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would want to iterate through your array. Something like the below should work.

```
String[] GameGenreCodeSeparated = GameGenreCodeRAW.split(",");
for (String GameGenre: GameGenreCodeSeparated ) { 
     listGameGenre.add(GameGenre);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a clearer explanation and work perfectly

Answer (score 4):

Use built-in method `Arrays.asList(GameGenreCodeRAW.split(","))` to avoid manually adding.

Answer (score 0):

@Sungakki You should check which approach is better and in this case, `Arrays.asList(GameGenreCodeRAW.split(","))` looks better approach which can help you in the future as well. 
The reason is Arrays.asList() is a standard utility method for dealing with Arrays. Writing custom for() loop makes no sense here.

If you are having difficulty in understanding what it is doing them below is further details on this.

Here is how you will use it in your code.

> listGameGenre = Arrays.asList(GameGenreCodeRAW.split(","));

`Arrays.asList()` simply returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array in our case it is GameGenreCodeRAW.

Here is the official documentation for `Arrays.asList()`  [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

I hope you understand my point.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create a new array or an arraylist because it's gonna be a hot mess trying to split a string but not store any data anywhere else.
Here is how I think it should be:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class test 
    {
        public static void split(String raw){
            ArrayList <String>  GameGenreCodeSeparated= new ArrayList<String>();
            int splits=0;//how man times have the sentence been splited
            int previousSplited=0;//index of the prevoius comma
            for(int i=0;i<raw.length();i++){
                if(raw.charAt(i)==','){//when comma occurs
                    if(previousSplited==0){//if this is the first comma
                        GameGenreCodeSeparated.add(raw.substring(0,i));//add the splited string to the list
                        previousSplited=i;//record the place where splited
                    }
                    else{
                        GameGenreCodeSeparated.add(raw.substring(previousSplited+1,i));//add the splited string to the list
                        previousSplited=i;//record the place where splited
                    }
                }
                else if (i==raw.length()-1){//if this is the end of the string
                    GameGenreCodeSeparated.add(raw.substring(previousSplited+1,i));//add the splited string to the list
                    previousSplited=i;//record the place where splited
                }

            }
            System.out.println(GameGenreCodeSeparated);//print out results;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
    String text = "In addition, Androids could multitask, whereas iPhones could not at that time. By 2011, Android outsold every other smartphone";

    String[] textSeparated = text.split(",");

String first=textSeparated[0];
String second=textSeparated[1];
String Third=textSeparated[2];
String Fourth=textSeparated[3];
```